# SOCKET.IO not send new data to the cilient, but old data (JavaScript Client)

Tags: javascript, sockets, websocket, socket.io

I have an issue, here I have some data to update and emited to the socket.io server.

1. I'm send some data like this

```
{
  act: 54,
  repair: 1,
  scrap: 2
}
```

2. And after sending that data via socket by emitting to the socket server. The socket server code like this

I'm using `request` and `request-promise` to update and get the data

```js
socket.on('updateMonitoringSeat', (monitoring_line_id, monitoring_seat_id, seat_id, data) => {
    baseRequestPromise.post(path('api/monitoring-seat/' + monitoring_seat_id), {form: data})
    .finally(() => {
        baseRequestPromise.get(path('api/monitoring-seat/' + monitoring_line_id)).then((body) => {
            io.in(`edun-central-${monitoring_line_id}`).emit('monitoringSeatData', body);
        });

        baseRequestPromise.get(path('api/monitoring-seat/' + monitoring_line_id + '/' + seat_id)).then((body) => {
            socket.join(`edun-${monitoring_line_id}-${seat_id}`);
            io.in(`edun-${monitoring_line_id}-${seat_id}`).emit('showMonitoringSeatData', body);
        });;
    });      
});
```

The data successfully updated in database. But, **sometime**, if I update the data fastly, after successfully updated, this code not send the updated data to the client, but the old data.

```js
baseRequestPromise.get(path('api/monitoring-seat/' + monitoring_line_id + '/' + seat_id)).then((body) => {
    socket.join(`edun-${monitoring_line_id}-${seat_id}`);
    io.in(`edun-${monitoring_line_id}-${seat_id}`).emit('showMonitoringSeatData', body);
});;
```

Anyone can fix this issue? Thanks in advance

Comment: can u show us the `baseRequestPromise.post` function ?

Comment: here is ``baseRequestPromise`` function [https://hastebin.com/ivovitetul.js](https://hastebin.com/ivovitetul.js)

Comment: hv u tried it with `async` `await` ?